# Folder won't open/greyed out

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, big-sur

I have a folder (recently transferred to my SSD from a friend’s hard drive) that is greyed out and won’t open. I checked online and noticed the date on the folder is January 24, 1984. It says online to:

> Step 1. Open Finder and find the grayed out folder or file that shows 24 January 1984 error.
> Step 2. Go to Applications and open the Terminal app.
> Step 3. Type SetFile -d 11/09/2016 /Path/to/grayed-out-folder/ and tap on return.

The title of the folder is “Haus VIDEO (Live Footage)”, (without the “”), so I tried to run this in Terminal:

```
SetFile -d 11/09/2016 SetFile -d 11/09/2020 /Volumes/RH SSD/Haus VIDEO (Live Footage)/
```

And I get this error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

What does that mean/how can I fix it?

Comment: Please [edit] to include a link to the source for quoted content. I've edited to add quote formatting and code formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Because your path argument contains space characters, in order for Terminal to understand your intent, you must escape each space character by preceding it with a back-slash ("\") OR surround the entire path argument with double quotes.  I think the parenthesis characters are "special" too, so escape those as well.  Thus:

```
/Volumes/RH\ SSD/Haus\ VIDEO\ \\(Live\ Footage\\)/
```

OR

```
"/Volumes/RH SSD/Haus VIDEO (Live Footage)/"
```

I'm a lazy typist, so I know which option I would try...

Comment: Is that right 'grg', double back-slash the parens?  Why?

Comment: Tab completion should work: type the start of the command up to "/Volumes/RH" and then hit the TAB key; it will probably insert "\ SSH" (assuming you only have one volume that starts "RH"). Keep typing, hitting TAB when you're not sure how to escape spaces, parentheses, other special characters.